# Set cookie to specific domains

Tags: php, iframe, cookies, ssl, authentication

I own a lot of subdomains, but only the main domain have SSL. On each subdomain there is a different website, and all are using the same CMS system, the same files and hosting (basicly it is redirects to the main domain and using PHP I show the site they want to see). I have one SSL to my main domain only. It won't work on subdomains obviously. So I thought to submit the form to the main domain from the subdomain using AJAX, but I guess it isn't safe, so I decided that I should use:

```
<iframe src="https://main.com/login.php?webid=958325&pageid=83985&hash=hjWR23grvw$%F$W"></iframe>
```

but the problem is the cookies. How can I create a cookie that will work on all subdomains, the main domain, and if it is possible, to some specific urls (that works the same way, but domain and not subdomain).

Comment: If you had a [wildcard SSL certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate) you could use the same certificate and have SSL for all your subdomains.

Comment: @SilverlightFox, I don't have wildcard SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/setcookie

The fifth and sixth parameter might interest you, which are respectively:

- (5th) domain
- (6th) secure

For example:

```
// This cookie will only be set to domain.com/folder if a secure connection exists and will expire once the browser closes.
setcookie('cookie', $variable, 0, 'folder/', 'domain.com', true);
```

Comment: And if I'll write in the domain google.com, will if affect Google? And is there a way to set a lot of domains (maybe array)? and how can I write "All subdomains of example.com"?

Comment: `example.com` will make the cookie valid for any subdomain such as `www.example.com`. As for the google-thing, I am not sure. I never tried it, but apparently you should be able to set cookies to remote domains, as far as I have read.

Comment: Ok, so but can I do something like that: `setcookie('cookie', $variable, 0, 'folder/', array('domain.com', 'otherdomain.com','domain.net'), false);`?

Comment: No. The parameter requires a `string` variable type. However you can use `foreach`, loop an array of the desidered domains and then set the cookie for all of them.

Comment: If you set `secure` to true it can't be read over plain HTTP (for the non-SSL subdomains).

Answer (score -1):

To have cookie working on all subdomains you need to set cookie to **.example.com** but it wont work on example.com, so you may need to set two cookies.

Comment: That is no longer true according to [RFC 6265](http://tools.ietf.org/search/rfc6265#page-20).